# Cannot view video after writing in python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, torchvision

Edit: The problem was fixed after using VLC media player. The standard windows media player could not read the videos.

I am attempting to take a video, run it through an object detector, add the bounding boxes, and output the video with the bounding boxes. However, I'm having a strange problem where the video I output cannot be viewed. I get a "Server execution failed" error when attempting to play the video on my local windows 10 machine. I am developing through SSH on ubuntu 20.04 with the vs code remote development extension.

Here is some OpenCV code that does not work with my setup. The video is written to the disk, and OpenCV is able to read frames from output5.avi, however the output5.avi file cannot be opened as I described.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mov")
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output5.avi', fourcc, 30, (width, height), isColor=True)

while cap.isOpened():
    # get validity boolean and current frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # if valid tag is false, loop back to start
    if not ret:
        break
    else:
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (width, height))
        out.write(frame)

cap.release()
out.release()
```

I have also attempted to save the video through torchvision.io.write_video, but the exact same problem occurs. Tensorboard similarly doesn't work.

It must be something wrong with how the remote machine is set up, but I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: read the file with VLC. does it work?

Comment: Did you make sure that the file path is correct?

Comment: @AnnZen Yes the file path is correct, I am able to read data from the output file. I am just not able to play the video, and get this weird error.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz VLC is not able to play it either. I got a different message after trying on a separate windows 10 machine: "This file isn't playable. That might be because the tile type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt." But I see nothing wrong with this code to cause the file to be corrupt.

Comment: What if you use `'mp4v'` instead of `'mjpg`' and output as mp4 format? In my experience, only the `'mp4v'` format works when the video is written with ubuntu and viewed on windows. Also, does the file size look correct?

Comment: This might have to do with the fourcc. [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) In the tutorial it states that it is platform dependent - maybe try to open it in the same OS the video was created in.

Comment: what size is the file? can you upload the file somewhere that will not try to convert this file (no youtube)? -- AVI and MJPEG are **built into OpenCV**. they *always* work. no dependencies. -- if that doesn't work, `out.release()` was never run. that happens if you kill the process.

Comment: if the issue happens with multiple libraries, perhaps your SSH stuff corrupted the file... try **not** doing all that abstraction/indirection/containerization. run that stuff locally.

Comment: @ihdv The same error occurs. Yes the file sizes are as expected, and I can even read the individual frames. But I can't play the video in a media player.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The file is 10 MB. I ran this code on my local computer and it still doesn't work. So SSH or platform is not the issue.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Are you saying there is an error in this code? If so what is it?

Comment: @code-lukas I ran this code with the same file on my local windows 10 computer and I get the same problem. Again, I am able to read individual frames from the read input video, but I am only not able to view the output video in a media player.

Comment: please upload such an unreadable file to somewhere (google drive, dropbox, ...)

Comment: Weird... I downloaded VLC again on a different computer and it works. I guess the problem was the media player, but it's strange it didn't seem to work on VLC on my computer. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @tonyd629, hi. You might consider answering your own question if it's been solved. Be as clear and detailed as possible. Thanks.